# Why did Widow tell Carter to hurry up?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, marvels-what-if

In *What if* S2:E5, Black Widow tells Captain Carter to hurry up and get into the plane as they are falling (with Steve Rogers in the Hydra busting armor). But Widow is below them, shouldn't the plane just have slowed down, or am I missing something here?

Planes generally have things in the wings that affect speed.

Answer (score 2):

Widow has extended the Quinjet's [dive-brakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dive_brake) to slow her descent as much as possible.

[image]

She's now relying on Carter making her and Steve's profile as aerodynamic as possible so that their airspeed exceeds hers and they can enter the bay, but obviously they don't have unlimited time to do this as the ground is approaching fast.